How to get clonezilla and do so safely?
I have been doing backups with partclone for a short while, and just discovered that it is part of Clonezilla, which may be a more convenient tool than using partclone directly.  It appears to be free, so I wanted to download a copy, clicking one of the bewildering array of stuff my search had returned.
It took me right down a "rabbit hole" -- weird messages claiming to be from Microsoft (why?  I'm doing this on Linux) and claiming I've been infected and if I don't do as they say my data will be deleted.
Sheesh!  So I closed the browser.
So how do I build or download a copy of Clonezilla without letting the bad guys steal everything before I get it backed up?

Clonezilla is packaged in Arch and Debian (and derivatives), so if you’re using one of those distributions you can install it safely using your package manager. For example:
sudo apt install clonezilla

Alternatively, you can download a live image from the official Clonezilla site.
